# How to populate markers in vue2-google-maps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-devtools

I'm really new to the whole js and I don't know much of the code.This is the package : https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps

And this has to be submitted next tomorrow. But here is what i've done so far. When i click on the button. I gotta show the markers in the map .

[image]

That is the result in my devtools after clicking on the button that has @click="showRoute"

```
 showRoute(){

this.fetchDeliveries() ;    


//I want then to populate the map with the marker with the given lat, lng in 
 the response
        }
```

on it and then

Answer (score 16):

Not enough data, but here is a working example of component which populates markers with data from your coordinates object

```
<teplate>
  <gmap-map ref="mymap" :center="startLocation" :zoom="14" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
    <gmap-info-window :options="infoOptions" :position="infoPosition" :opened="infoOpened" @closeclick="infoOpened=false">
    {{infoContent}}
    </gmap-info-window>
    <gmap-marker v-for="(item, key) in coordinates" :key="key" :position="getPosition(item)" :clickable="true" @click="toggleInfo(item, key)" />
  </gmap-map>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    startLocation: {
      lat: 10.3157,
      lng: 123.8854
    },
    coordinates: {
      0: {
        full_name: 'Erich  Kunze',
        lat: '10.31',
        lng: '123.89'
      },
      1: {
        full_name: 'Delmer Olson',
        lat: '10.32',
        lng: '123.89'
      }
    },
    infoPosition: null,
    infoContent: null,
    infoOpened: false,
    infoCurrentKey: null,
    infoOptions: {
      pixelOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: -35
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPosition: function(marker) {
      return {
        lat: parseFloat(marker.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(marker.lng)
      }
    },
    toggleInfo: function(marker, key) {
      this.infoPosition = this.getPosition(marker)
      this.infoContent = marker.full_name
      if (this.infoCurrentKey == key) {
        this.infoOpened = !this.infoOpened
      } else {
        this.infoOpened = true
        this.infoCurrentKey = key
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/burlakko/kc8Ljejv/31/

Comment: Yeah I defined a two sets of gmap-markers the first mainly does on where the user would type on the autocomplete and then move that marker to that location.

The other is for the markers of returned coordinates that has this  properties : customer_parcel_id WHICH I USE as key (AM I right ) ??,  lat , lng ,

Comment: Can you please revise your code, I get an error that there's an unexpected token.

Comment: @d3cypher can you show your component's code? it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the code

Comment: as a guess... maybe coordinates should be numbers not strings. so you can try 
    <gmap-marker v-for="({ lat, lng }, key) in coordinates" :key="key" :position="{ lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) }" />

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/aiboom/w7b2gzsr/5/ ) Sorry for being away. Can you please see my code ?

Comment: @d3cypher your piece of code is not informative enough. E.g.what is the this.fetchDeliveries() function?
But anyway i updated the answer with working fiddle example of populating googl map markers with data from your coordinates object. That should be enough to solve your problem

Comment: It's just a plain ajax call to

Comment: The response of that would be something like this. 

![capture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12043306/37222165-1f5e3dda-2407-11e8-9871-633022da7769.JPG). I've also update my fiddle : 


https://jsfiddle.net/w7b2gzsr/7/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the position of the gmap-marker after you dragg it on the map?

Comment: @KasparTr yeah that's possible my friend'